# How do I know how python core is working?

Tags: python

How do I know how the core python will work.

For ex see the below code:

```
class A(object):
    def a(self):
        print 111111
    def b(self):
        self.a()

class B(A):
    def a(self):
        print 222222
```

When I do

```
a = B()
a.b()
```

it is printing

```
222222
```

What could be the reason why it did not print "11111", if you say 'self' is the object of class B, so its calling its own method, but where it is defined that 'self' is the object of class B?

Where do I see the internal logic that's calling 'a' method from class B?

Every time I came across this logic, I forget and assumes that it prints '111111', so is there any way I can check the internal python behavior?

Comment: Learn about [method overriding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that `self.a` refers to `A.a` just because it occurs in the definition of `A.b`. That's not true; the behavior of `self.a` is determined by the *runtime* type of `self`.

Since `a` is an instance of `B`, `a.b()` is the same as `type(a).b(a, b)` or `B.b(a, b)`. Since `B.b` is not defined, the attribute lookup process falls back to `A.b`. Inside  `A.b`, `self == a`, so we now have `a.a()`, which again is equivalent to `type(a).a(a) == B.a(a)`. As a result, `A.a` never gets called.